# How to convert current VIew to a high res PDF to email

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, pdf, xcode5

I currently have code to take a screen grab of the current view (containing a PNG imageview with editable text fields over it) but the jpg it creates is 72ppi.

My original png is 326ppi.

How do I capture or create a PDF of the current view with the apx 326 ppi?

I read a bunch of other posts but none of them were for this purpose.

any help would be great.

here's the code i am using now:

```
- (IBAction)SnapSend:(id)sender {


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];


    }


    NSLog(@" please add image to my message");


    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];
    [mc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];



    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];



}



- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


@end
```

Comment: You should tag the appropriate language/framework (Objective C?) to get better responses

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` doesn't let you specify the ppi embedded in the JFIF data it produces.  It puts 72 dpi in the JFIF if you give it a non-retina image (which you are doing), and 144 if you give it a retina image.

First, you should change your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and specify a scale of 2.0 to create a retina image.

Then, you need to use the ImageIO framework to create the JFIF data, and you need the MobileCoreServices framework for the constant that specifies the JFIF type.

So, you have a `UIImage` in variable `image`.  The following code create JFIF data from that image and sets 326 ppi:

```
NSMutableData *mutableData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(
    (__bridge CFMutableDataRef)mutableData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);

NSDictionary *properties = @{
    (__bridge id)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: @0.5,
    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: @326,
    (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: @326,
};
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage,
    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);
```

The resulting JFIF data is in `mutableData`.

Comment: sorry ya lost me there with JFIF. I'm not familiar with that image format.Can you enlighten me? Personally I'd rather it creates a PDF at the resolution of the original png (in my resources file) that includes the content textfields at that moment. But if this gets me there great. I have

Comment: JPEG is a compression method. JFIF is [“JPEG File Interchange Format”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format).  It is the format used in `.jpg` files.  If you want to create a PDF, just create a PDF.  Check out [`UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData).

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the dpi. (or ppi).

This is the key:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
```

That statement sets the graphic context in x and y resolution (width and height respectively);

That defines the absolute resolution of your output. 
When you increase that by the factor of 4.23 (roughly), which is the scale factor of 72 ppi to 326, then you would have to align your self.view geometry accordingly.

It is as simple as that: If you want these number of pixels to be drawn then you will have to draw exaclty this number of pixels.

Comment: that sounds viable but wouldnt it just be scaling up a 72ppi image and then get more pixelated - chunky looking?